# App is not opening and force shuts down on Samsung Galaxy S22

Tags: android, firebase, facebook-login, mobile-application, samsung-galaxy

Samsung Galaxy S22 users are complaining that they cannot open the app and we are not getting any new crash logs regarding this issue on firebase. System is presenting them with the following error:

> "Something went wrong with APP
>
> APP closed because this app has a bug.
>
> Try updating this app after its developer provides a fix for this
> error."

[image: This message varies slightly different.]

Answer (score 0):

After contacting Samsung developers - the reason for this error is that the app uses an OpenSSL version lower than 1.1.1l . Upgrading OpenSSL version to this version and above should fix the issue.

In more details:

Open SSL 1.1.1b~h or 2.x version has PAC-related defect (Pointer Authentication Code).
The reason why S22 especially has force close with the app is S22 has PAC failure detecting logic.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and solved it by upgrading my work manager dependencies to use version 2.7.1. It seems Samsung is blocking older versions of the work manager library

```
//Java only 
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1"

// Kotlin + coroutines
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

We got this crash in work and the reason for no logs was it was a Java crash called from native code. Our custom ExceptionHandler didn't catch it. So a Java callback containing a bug invoked from native code, not Java calling a native method direct, that was caught by the handler normal.

We only  found the real bug when the user sent us the device and we could see the full device LogCat, which had the stacktrace. So maybe get a technical user who has this error to run your app and copy/paste their full LogCat.

[Java UncaughtExceptionHandler haven't got any exception using JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39127512/java-uncaughtexceptionhandler-havent-got-any-exception-using-jni) has more details on JNI and ExceptionHandler.